# Installing fftw-2.1.5 with openMPI

Tags: openmpi, fftw

Trying to install fftw to use [GADGET2](https://astrobites.org/2011/04/02/installing-and-running-gadget-2/), and after running the following command:

```
./configure --enable-mpi --enable-type-prefix --enable-float
```

I get the message:

```
checking for mpicc... mpicc
checking for MPI_Init... no
checking for MPI_Init in -lmpi... no
checking for MPI_Init in -lmpich... no
configure: error: couldn't find mpi library for --enable-mpi
```

Now I have installed openMPI already, so it seems to be the case that it just can't find it. There was a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142504/install-fftw-2-1-5-with-mpi-in-local) posted a while ago with different mpi software. I think the problem is that my openMPI and other compilers might be in different folders? This brings me to a more general question (I have tried googling this but can't find anything that explains it well):

If I extract a tar and use ./configure without any prefix, where will the program install to? And is this is an issue that my openMPI has for some reason installed to a different place?

Thanks!

edit: found a solution for this from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738667/problem-with-mpicc), where just running

```
sudo ldconfig
```

seemed to fix it and now it compiles fine.

Comment: Check if the `mpicc` command works.

Comment: It doesn't - in my `/usr/local/bin` I have the following: `lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     12 Aug 14 18:24 mpicc -> opal_wrapper`.