# Problems between fftw-2.1.5 libraries and OpenMPI

Tags: openmpi, fftw

I am trying to install the MPI FFTW2 libraries (fftw2.1.5) as I need them for a program that only works with that version. The specific library I need is "drfftw_mpi.h" so I try the followed:

```
  ./configure --enable-mpi --enable-type-prefix
```

But it always gives me the following error:

```
configure: error: couldn't find mpi library for --enable-mpi
```

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680160/installing-fftw-2-1-5-with-openmpi?noredirect=1&lq=1) they solve it by running `sudo ldconfig` before, but for me it does not work giving the same error. For other mpi software they solve it [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142504/install-fftw-2-1-5-with-mpi-in-local) by passing mpicc as the right compiler to ./configure, with the CC flag `CC=mpicc`, something that does not work for me.

I have installed Open MPI version 4.0.3 on a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, and when --enable-mpi  is not used I was able to install "dfftw.h"  "drfftw.h"  "fftw.h" and "rfftw.h", do you have an idea of what I am doing wrong or what should I do to install "drfftw_mpi.h"?